# Dictionaries- narrowing down a value and printing which keys belong to it - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm sorting through a dictionary and trying to go through it and determine which of the dictionary keys in "food_type" has the corresponding value of "fruit". So far going through this the farthest my code below takes me is :

```
def  fruit (food_type):


         for f in food_type.values():
                if f=="fruit" :
                    return(f)

fruit ({'apple': 'fruit', 'lettuce': 'veggie', 'banana':'fruit'})
```

This just returns "fruit" once, so I'm not 100% if that's what I want in this case since my end goal is to have the value reflected back to the dictionary and return the keys that have "fruit" as their value. I know that in order to get a value you can just do : d[k] or d.get(k) etc.

I'm looking for an output the following for this:

```
["apple","banana"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to iterate through `(key, value)` pairs, accumulate matches to a list and then return that list.

A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) gets the job done nicely:

```
def fruit(food_type):
    return [k for k, v in food_type.items() if v == 'fruit']
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're after:

```
def  fruit (food_type):
    return [k for k in food_type if food_type[k] == "fruit"]

print fruit ({'apple': 'fruit', 'lettuce': 'veggie', 'banana':'fruit'})

# ['apple', 'banana']
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will return you the new dictionary with just the entries with value equal to 'fruit':

```
>>> d = {'apple': 'fruit', 'lettuce': 'veggie', 'banana':'fruit'}
>>> {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v == 'fruit'}
{'apple': 'fruit', 'banana': 'fruit'}
```

If you want just the keys, simply call keys() method on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also inverse your dictionary with :

```
inverse_d = {}
for k, v in d.iter_items():
    if v not in inverse_d:
        inverse_d[v] = [k]
    else :
        inverse_d[v].append(k)
```

and then

```
print inverse_d["fruit"]
```

Comment: `dict.setdefault` or `collections.defaultdict` would remove the need for an if/else block.

Comment: I know. I judged that this was easier to understand for a beginner.

Comment: Thanks for putting it in simpler terms. I'm fairly new to Python.